# Let $N$ be a star-cyclic normal operator and $\lambda \in \sigma_p(N)$ show $\text{dim ker}(T-\lambda)=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $N$ be a star-cyclic normal operator and $\lambda \in \sigma_p(N)$ show that $\text{dim ker}(T-\lambda)=1$ , that is $ \sigma_p(N)$ denote the set of eigenvalues of $N.$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, normal operator is said to be closed linear operator, what is the meaning of closed here? https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Normal_operator

Comment: [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Conway proves in Theorem 3.4, you can think of $N$ as $N_\mu$. If $f\in \ker(N-\lambda)$ then
$$
zf(z)=\lambda f(z),\ \ \ z\in K.
$$
When $z\ne\lambda$, we have $f(z)=0$. So $f(z)=\alpha\,1_{\{\lambda\}}$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb C$. That is, $\ker(N-\lambda)=\mathbb C\,1_{\{\lambda\}}$.

Comment: Martin Argerami, Thank you for your time and attention